# Mysql: Join only when column is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a query in MySQL to fetch a list of images. The  problem is that, I want to join another table only when a column is not null.

images:

```
|id|image                                                               |user_id|circle_id|is_deleted|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |cdb10bee27262c597619fdef25bae0eb673f5d5d1b9b33697e40906ad851a25b.jpg|30     |1        |0         |
|2 |9e3213276225b900a3e19262a7761ec3fdf608b95441aa8fbc012f246514d394.jpg|30     |1        |0         |
|3 |a51e104c82de33a804ae0a09e719f3cd7aa205a0830eab4e1e4aa26fd8a6313d.jpg|30     |NULL     |0         |
```

circles_users:

```
|id|circle_id|user_id|
----------------------
|1 |1        |31     |
```

users:

```
|id|username|
-------------
|30|elk     |
|31|moose   |
```

Initially, I came up with this, but after inspection, I realised it would not work.

```
SELECT images.*
FROM images
    LEFT JOIN circles_users ON circles_users.circle_id = images.circle_id
WHERE (circles_users.user_id = '31' OR images.circle_id IS NULL)
    AND images.user_id = '30'
    AND images.is_deleted = '0'
LIMIT 16
```

I can't seem to get it right anyhow, so I decided to write some *pseudo* sql to illustrate what I wish to achieve

```
SELECT images.*
    FROM images

        CASE
            WHEN images.circle_id IS NOT NULL 
            THEN LEFT JOIN circles_users ON circles_users.circle_id = images.circle_id AND circles_users.user_id = '32'
        END CASE

    WHERE images.user_id = '30'
    AND images.is_deleted = '0'
    LIMIT 16
```

Hope you get what I mean. Thanks for the help.

Basically, I want to fetch all images posted by a user (poster) has if another user is in the circle shared by the poster or if the circle_id is null

Comment: I don't understand the problem

Comment: If you do not want NULLs in your result try changining the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

Comment: I think some sample data and an expected output would help.

Comment: @GarethD hope it makes sense now

Comment: I think it does, with the data you have posted for User 30 should it only display image 3 because it has a NULL circle and use 30 is not in any circles so all the images with a not null circle should be excluded? And if User 30 was in circle 1, should it return all images?

Comment: @GarethD it should return all images actually

Comment: @GarethD, the problem is this. If the circle_id is null, then it is public so all users should see it. Else, it is limited to that circle and only members of that circle can see it.

Comment: That is what I thought, so why can user 30 see all three images in your sample data when they are not a member of circle 1?

Comment: Actually, I am checking for user 31s circles. I'm so dumb. My original query works as expected. I've been working so long I began testing on wrong data. Thanks a bunch for the effort and the time. I appreciate it much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `INNER JOIN` if I understand your question.

Comment: This. Just change `LEFT` to `INNER` and you won't get any NULL joins

Comment: I'm guessing my question is not coming through well enough.  Basically, if circle_id is null, I still want to return the image. If it isn't, then I'd like to join on the circles_users

Comment: I've just come across a left outer join, and I suspect that will do the trick for me.

Comment: But it doesn't work. It only returns rows which have a circle id.

Comment: Actually, my first query does what I Want it to do. I was testing it on wrong data. Thanks for the  effort!

Answer (score 1):

Then Change your query to something like

```
SELECT im.*
FROM images im
    LEFT JOIN circles_users cu ON cu.circle_id = im.circle_id AND cu.user_id = '31'
WHERE im.user_id = '30'
    AND im.is_deleted = '0'
LIMIT 16
```

Comment: Actually, my first query does what I Want it to do. I was testing it on wrong data. Thanks for the  effort!

Answer (score 0):

My test data was flawed and my trust in my sql knowledge ahaky. The original query is correct and works as expected.

SELECT images.*
FROM images
    LEFT JOIN circles_users ON circles_users.circle_id = images.circle_id
WHERE (circles_users.user_id = '31' OR images.circle_id IS NULL)
    AND images.user_id = '30'
    AND images.is_deleted = '0'
LIMIT 16

EXPLANATION
When the query is run, it fetches all images with user_id = 30. If circle_id is not null, it fetches the corresponding circles_users row else nothing as it is a left join
The Where statement then checks if the circles_users.user_id (if it exists) = 31 else it checks if images.circle_id is null  effectively achieving the What I aimed to.